# AngularJS $scopes behave like a pointer

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have something like:

```
$scope.array1_copy=$scope.array1[$scope.index];
```

`$scope.array1` ist an array, made out from smaller arrays filled with objects.
Now, when I take changes to $scope.array1_copy the changes get reflected in $scope.array1. 
I've read of using `angular.copy()`, but whats the reason for this behaviour?

Kind regards;
Force0234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Angular, the reason it happens is because objects and arrays are passed by reference in JavaScript.
you could use `slice()` to clone the array.

```
$scope.array1_copy = $scope.array1[$scope.index].slice();
```

Read more here: http://orizens.com/wp/topics/javascript-arrays-passing-by-reference-or-by-value/

Answer (score 0):

In javascript when you assign a object to another, is passing the reference of this object, the angular copy create a new object and copy de primitive values inside and return this reference. Example:

```
var object = {
    value: "value",
    value2: "value2",
    ...
}

var object2 = object;
object2.value = "change this value";
console.log(object.value) // must print "change this value"

var value = object.value;
value = "another value";
console.log(object.value) // must print "change this value" mantain the old value

//Deep copy
var object2 = {}
object2.value = object.value;
object2.value2 = object.value2;
object2.value = "another change to this value";
console.log(object.value) // must print "change this value" mantain the old value
```